# How to pause execution in Powershell (Windows) similar to Unix CTRL-z and 'fg'?

Tags: powershell

Is there an equivalent command in Powershell (windows terminal) for pausing execution similar to Unix <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>?

If yes, what is the equivalent command to resume it, similar to the `fg` command?

Comment: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/04/18/background-jobs-in-powershell.aspx - the PS-Specific Job management. Also, a shell like `bash` (mingw/cygwin) will operate on the process level; in this case PowerShell would be the process :}

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/465238/is-there-an-analog-of-bashs-ctrlz-fg-in-powershell - appears the answer is "There is no direct equivalent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with <kbd>Pause Break</kbd>, and resume with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: The question says "pause", but Ctrl+Z/fg actually relates to *background* jobs: a method of running and switching between multiple programs from a single console.

Comment: Sorry, what keys do I hit for  "Pause Break"?

Comment: Nice pic, I'm using a mac and doing remote desktop. I'll try to google equivalent key on mac.

Comment: If the remote desktop is a windows machine, you can launch an on-screen keyboard with c:\Windows\System32\osk.exe